# Creating navigation property between 3 entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 3 entities that I am trying to create a mapping between.

```
[Table("ContentItem")]
public class ContentItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }

    [Column("PageID")]
    public int PageID { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentType ContentType { get; set; }

    [Column("ContentTypeID")]
    public int ContentTypeID { get; set; }

    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContentType")]
public class ContentType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual HTMLContent HtmlContent { get; set; }    
 }

[Table("HTMLContent")]
public class HTMLContent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    [Column("PageID")]
    public int PageID { get; set; }

    [Column("ContentTypeID")]
    public int ContentTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have the relationship between ContentType and HTMLContent mapped using the Fluent API like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/10/06/removing-edmmetadata-table-in-ef-code-first.aspx
    // We don't need the EdmMetadata table in the DB
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<ContentType>().HasRequired(b => b.HtmlContent);

}
```

Right now using Linq to access HTMLContent like this:

`var contentItems = cmsUnitOfWork.ContentItems.Find().Where(x => x.PageID == 1).ToList();`

I am able to access HTMLContent in my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<H2O.Domain.CMS.Models.ContentItem>

@foreach(var x in Model)
{
    <div id="ContentItem@(x.ID)">
    <strong>@x.ContentType.HtmlContent.Content
    </div>
}
```

However, it is only giving me the first HTMLContent row in the database.  I would like this to return the HTMLContent with ID that corresponds to the ItemID member inside ContentItem Entity.  Since ItemID could come from a different ID other than HTMLContent I cannot map a direct foreign key.  How can I do this with Entity?

Comment: Im a little confused by your example, is your intention to have a 1:1 relationsip between ContentType and HtmlContent?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this MVC myself but I think i can see what you need to do. You may want to look at creating a View-Model. Rather than try to access nested objects in MVC which I haven't figured yet, you could build a class, tailored for your specific needs.

something like this :-

```
 public class ViewHtmContentAndContentItem
    {
      public ContentItem contentItems {get; set;}
      public HTMLContent HtmlContentItems {get; set;}
    }
```

Now, when you do your Linq query, you can join both tables on the `PageId` in both tables and return this object to your View.

Form there you can access which ever properties you require.

Hope this helps.